# Use a different delivery_method with ActionMailer just for a single email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Given a `Mailer` instance in Rails 3, is there a way to override the `delivery_method` on it?

I want to push certain emails out through a high-priority transport, and others use a busier, low-priority method.

I can adjust the config at runtime and change it back again, but this is fraught with potential side-effects.

Comment: Are you using delayed job or any other queing system? If yes you are most probably using them to enque all of your emails. You can setup an EMAIL_ENV(each having different ActionMailer config), similar to RAILS_ENV and start different workers with different EMAIL_ENV. In case some mail gets directly delivered through application, you can have a sensible default for EMAIL_ENV.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I'm doing.  I didn't describe my problem as it actually exists :)  I'm sending mails out through my own `:queued` delivery method (into Resque, which does some additional tracking) and then from Resque I need to send them out over SMTP.  It turns out setting `delivery_method` (class method) from within a subclass of `ActionMailer::Base` does not actually have a global impact and does what I need :)  We send other emails via our Resque queue, so I didn't want to change that entire environment (I know I could configure different workers differently).

Comment: Good to know that something like that exists and doesn't have a global impact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that doing this affects just this specific Mailer, without changing `ActionMailer::Base` globally.

```
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  self.delivery_method = :high_priority  

  def some_email(params)
  end
end
```

You can also do this (warning: will affect all instances of `AnotherMailer`), if you have the instance up-front:

```
mail = AnotherMailer.whatever_email
mail.delivery_handler.delivery_method = :something_else
```

These don't seem to be documented, but work.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little the `:high_priority` or point me towards the resource. I had just implemented the EMAIL_ENV approach, but haven't pushed it to production yet. I am tending towards trying out the simpler solution. :)

Comment: The above just assumes you've written your own delivery method and added it to action mailer with `ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :high_priority, YourHighPrioritySender` (which just implements `deliver!`).  You could replace `:high_priority` with `:smtp` if you're using an out-of-the-box delivery method.

Comment: I'll post a gist (will have to dumb it down a bit, as it's work stuff).

Comment: Here's more or less the entire thing.  Delayed_job would simplify things (you can't put objects on the queue in Resque, you can only pass simple data structures, then use those to look up objects).  We also want to keep a record of all email sent too, as we analyze the data https://gist.github.com/1176236

Comment: thanks for the gist, things are a lot clearer now. One more question though, similar to `delivery_method` can one also override `smtp_settings` in mailer? I will test it out, if I can? But even if it works, I have no clue how to test or know if it is thread safe. I particularly want to send different emails through different smtp relay servers. If you have any idea, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that you can, yes.  It seems like the attributes are linked with the subclass and not with `ActionMailer::Base`.  If you're doing that to send concurrently, you might be able to create singleton subclasses and override the settings in each instance.

Answer (score -1):

I used to do that in a Rails 2 application where some emails were sent via ActionMailer and others were sent via ArMailer. It's not a bad solution as long as you don't change the delivery method back in the same delivery because it could cause the delivery method not to be changed in case of error with the delivery, this is what a I made:

```
class Mailer1

  def my_mail1
    config
  end

private

  def config 
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  end

end


class Mailer2

  def my_mail2
    config
  end

private

  def config 
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
  end

end
```

Comment: Changing ActionMailer::Base like that has a global impact and may result in race conditions, I think.